# How to exclude specific selection from query

Tags: php, sql

I have this function for email checking in registration form which disables submit button if submitted email is currently in use. So I want to modify that function in profile edit section. I also have profile edit form in profile.php. So when user edits his info withouth touching email input it works fine. But once user clicks and to email field and blurs out the mouse without even editing something it shows "Email Already Taken" error. Which is fine cause function works for registeration form. So when user submits different email I want to check if it's already in db otherwise if he doesn't change anything I want to show nothing and proceed.

I've tried to solve this in back end with this query:

```
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND id != ?
 .

 .

 .
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $uid);
```

but it doesn't work

Then I tried SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?

and looped over selection to detect if there is selection with id = uid. If yes, make result variable 0. But it also doesn't work.

```
function profEmailCheck(){
    $('#email').blur(function(){

       var email = $(this).val();
       var uid = $('#uid').val(); 

       var update_email_check = '';
       $.ajax({
        url:'update_email_check.php',
        method:"POST",
        data:{
            update_email_check: update_email_check,
            email: email,
            uid: uid
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
         if(data != 0)
         {
          $('.email-availability').html('<span class="text-danger">Email Already Taken</span>');
          $('#update-prof-btn').attr("disabled", true);
         }
         else
         {
            if (email == '') 
            {
              $('.email-availability').html('');  
              $('#update-prof-btn').attr("disabled", true);  
            }
            else
            {
              $('.email-availability').html('<span class="text-success">Email Available</span>');
              $('#update-prof-btn').attr("disabled", false);    
            }


         }
        }
       })

    });

  }
```

```php
<?php

include('db_connect.php');

if (isset($_POST["update_email_check"])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["uid"]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND id != ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
        exit();
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $uid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    }

    $result = mysqli_sql($conn, $sql);

    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        if($rows['id'] == $uid){
            $result = '0';
        }
    }
    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
```

Comment: Remove `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn`. Do not use that function if you use prepared statements. It will only break your data.

Comment: @Dharman ok I will. But as you can see I was telling you that I am gonna use prepared statements at the end and I did :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to check email control.

```
If (exists){
Do something
}
else {
Do something
}
```

If this is what you want then you should;

```
$ControlMailQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
$ControlMailQueryResult = mysqli_query($db, $ControlMailQuery);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($ControlMailQueryResult) == 1){
//There is a one user who has this email
}
else{
//this is unique e-mail address
}
```

Comment: Yes but problem here is user himself must be able to use his email adress regardless the result of query. User has current email adress in db and he doesn't want to change it. But if he accidentally clicks to input field he gets the error. So I want to exclude user himself from results of query. That's what I need.